# How can we use html <input type= ""> for Django model form?

Tags: html, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

using this for django model form, we cant create beautiful front end.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="esor">
       Name: {{form.Name}}<br>
       Class: {{form.Class}}<br>
       Publisher: {{form.Publisher}}<br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Isn't there any ways so we can use html code like:

```
<form method="GET" action="#">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of book">
</form>
```

instead of {{form.Name}} or {{form.as_p}}

Comment: I think this one  you might to help full https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get a beautiful interface that way, just pass the name you use in the form.py

#### Example:

***forms.py***

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            "whatever"
        ]
```

***Html Template***

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="whatever" placeholder="Write whatever">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approach I normally use:

Install [widget tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks), so you can customize your input easily:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{{ form.Name|add_class:"css_class"|attr:"placeholder:Name of book" }}
```

Or 2, in your `forms.py`, set all the attributes you want for the field:

```
Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name of book'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving the name of your input element same as the name of your form field. And you can get name of your form field by displaying {{ form }} in html and then inspecting the form field in your browser and then the name attribute of that field will be name of the form field.